# Use Proc Summary Statistic in Another Data Step

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that contains a list of employees and the number of hours they work.

```
  Name      Hours_CD_Max
  Bob        455
  Dan        675
  Jane       543
  Suzzy      575
  Emily      234
```

I used a proc summary datastep to calculate the number of total hours worked by these employees.

```
Proc summary data = staff;
where position = 'PA_FT_UMC';                                  
var Hours_CD_Max;
output out=PAFT_Only_Staff_Totals 
sum = Hours_CD_Max_tot;
run;
```

I would like to use the 'Hours_CD_Max_tot' statistic (2482) from this proc summary datastep and apply to other occurrences within my code where I need to make calculations.

For example, I want to take each providers current hours and divide it by Hours_CD_Max_tot.

So for example, create a dataset that looks like this

```
  data PA_FT_UMC_StaffingV2;
  set PA_FT_UMC_StaffingV1 PAFT_Only_Staff_Totals;
  if position = 'PA_FT_UMC'; 
  PA_FT_Max_Percent= Hours_CD_Max/Hours_CD_Max_tot;                             
  run;

  Name      Hours_CD_Max    Hours_CD_Max_tot
  Bob        455                  2482
  Dan        675                  2482 
  Jane       543                  2482
  Suzzy      575                  2482
  Emily      234                  2482
```

I realize I can calculate the % of hours worked using a proc freq but I really would like to have that (2482) number to be freely available so I can plug it into more complex equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a macro variable from it and SQL is the fastest solution.

```
 proc sql noprint;
  select sum(hours_cd_max) into :hours_max
  from have;
 quit;
```

Then you can use it in your calculations later on, using `&hours_max`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a variable from another dataset then pull it into your current code.

If there are BY variables you can merge it onto your other dataset.  If this case where you just have one observation just run a SET command on the first iteration of the data step.

```
data PA_FT_UMC_StaffingV2;
  set PA_FT_UMC_StaffingV1 PAFT_Only_Staff_Totals;
  if _n_=1 then set PAFT_Only_Staff_Totals(keep=Hours_CD_Max_tot);
  if position = 'PA_FT_UMC'; 
  PA_FT_Max_Percent= Hours_CD_Max/Hours_CD_Max_tot;                             
run;
```